# Rendering of the timer stops while routing from one component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, setinterval

So I have made a simple countdown timer which stops rendering the updated time if I route to another component. I have used a `setInerval()` which updates the countdown time every second, and whenever I route to another component the `setInterval()` keeps running but no rendering happens and the countdown timer sets back to its starting time.

App

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Countdown from "./components/Countdown";
import Timer from "./components/Timer";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Countdown />} />
        <Route path="timer" element={<Timer />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Countdown

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Countdown = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(600);

  const startTimer = () => {
    const start = Date.now();
    const updateTime = () => {
      const updatedTime = time - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);
      setTime(updatedTime);
      console.log("Set Interval running");
    };
    setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
  };

  const minutes = (time / 60) | 0;
  const seconds = time % 60 | 0;
  return (
    <>
      <h3>
        {minutes}:{seconds}
      </h3>
      <p>Start the timer first </p>
      <button onClick={startTimer}>START</button>
      <p>After starting the timer go this component </p>
      <Link to="timer">
        <button>Go to Timer</button>
      </Link>
    </>
  );
};

export default Countdown;
```

Timer

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Timer = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>
        Now go back to the Countdown component, the timer is reset and the
        setInterval() is still running. How can I avoid this issue ?
      </p>
      <Link to="/">
        <button>Go back to Countdown</button>
      </Link>
    </>
  );
};

export default Timer;
```

Here's the link to the application - [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-blackburn-31dmqv?file=/src/components/Countdown.js)

With my little beginner knowledge I tried to store the updated time in `localStorage` every second and then whenever the component rerenders back I tried to fetch it from `localStorage` and start the timer but it didn't work as anything inside the `setInterval()` did't work when routed to another component.

Answer (score 1):

The state value of time is relevant only for the active component. If you hop onto a different component and then come back, the state value resets.

To avoid this you can set up context API which helps in data sharing between components.

Check out [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-context-api-deep-dive-examples/) to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The issue you see here is caused by the state being located in the `Countdown` component. When you navigate from the `"/"` route to the `"/timer"` route `Countdown` is unmounted. The reason the interval is still running is because there is no cleanup function to clear the interval when `Countdown` unmounts.

## Solution

The solution is to [Lift State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a common ancestor and pass the `time` state and `startTimer` callback down as props to children/descendent components that care for them.

Since you are using `react-router-dom` a trivial solution would be to render a  layout route component that holds the state and setter and provides them via a React Context.

Example:

TimerLayout

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const TimerLayout = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(600);
  const timerRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timerRef.current);
    };
  }, []);

  const startTimer = () => {
    console.log("Set Interval running");
    setTime(600);

    const tick = () => {
      setTime((time) => time - 1);
    };

    timerRef.current = setInterval(tick, 1000);
  };

  return <Outlet context={{ startTimer, time }} />;
};

export default TimerLayout;
```

App

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import TimerLayout from "./components/TimerLayout";
import Countdown from "./components/Countdown";
import Timer from "./components/Timer";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<TimerLayout />}>
        <Route path="/" element={<Countdown />} />
        <Route path="timer" element={<Timer />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Consumers would access the provided Context value using the `useOutletContext` hook. Here the `minutes` and `seconds` remaining can be derived from the passed `time` state.

CountDown

```
import { Link, useOutletContext } from "react-router-dom";

const Countdown = () => {
  const { time, startTimer } = useOutletContext();

  const minutes = String(Math.floor(time / 60)).padStart(2, "0");
  const seconds = String(time % 60).padStart(2, "0");

  return (
    <>
      <h3>
        {minutes}:{seconds}
      </h3>
      <p>Start the timer first </p>
      <button onClick={startTimer}>START</button>
      <p>After starting the timer go this component </p>
      <Link to="timer">
        <button type="button">Go to Timer</button>
      </Link>
    </>
  );
};

export default Countdown;
```

[image: Edit rendering-of-the-timer-stops-while-routing-from-one-component-to-another]